# CollectionView cell inside UITableView is repeating

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, contentsize

I have one table view in which every cell contains one collection view!

1) display only two cell in collectionview as my issue is when we scroll the tableview, collectoinview cell content is repeated in many other cell of tableview

myCode:

```
let tags = Tblarr[indexPath.row]["hashtags"] as! [String]
    if tags.count != 0
    {
        for var i in 0 ... tags.count - 1
        {
            if i < 2
            {
                cell.tagsView.addTag(tags[i])
                cell.collectionView.isHidden =   false
            }
        }
        if tags.count > 2
        {
            cell.lblCount.isHidden = false
            cell.lblCount.text = "+\(tags.count - 2)"
        }
        else
        {
            cell.lblCount.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    else{
        cell.lblCount.isHidden = true
        cell.collectionView.isHidden =   true
    }
    cell.fillCollectionView(with: cell.tagsView.tags)
    cell.widthConstraint.constant = cell.collectionView.contentSize.width
```

here I get only fixed width of collectionview without setting width according to content size & collectionview cells are repeated in other cell of tableview, even if cell is one , it will show 2 cell(when scrolled)

when load for the first time

[image: when load for the first time]

when tableview is scrolled

[image: when tableview is scrolled]

//for storing array in collectionview from tableview

```
func fillCollectionView(with array: [String]) {
    self.collectionArr = array
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

reload collectionView inside tableview

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
cell.fillCollectionView.reloadData()
}`

```
func fillCollectionView(with array: [String]) {
self.collectionArr.removeAll
self.collectionArr = array
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

}

Comment: fillCollectionView is function for storing array & within it collectionview is also reloaded

Comment: fillCollectionView(with array: [Your String]) call this method inside cellForRowAt indexPath

Comment: before reload collection you have to clear collectionView array list

Comment: like 'func fillCollectionView(with array: [String]) {
self.collectionArr.removeAll()    
self.collectionArr = array
 self.collectionView.reloadData()
}'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `fillCollectionView` does but it looks like you didn't consider that the table view cells are reused. So every time you call `fillCollectionView` you have to reset the content of your cell or the content or your collection view.

Comment: how to reset it can u plz help more @cldrr

Comment: Try to call `cell.tagsView.tags = []` before `let tags = Tblarr...`

The cell is being reused, means that the object itself can contain data from a previous usage.